# Mantener popup hijo por delante en firefox y chrome?

Tags: javascript

Estoy viendo como dejar una ventana hija sobre la padre de modo que no se pueda interactuar sobre la ventana padre sin cerrar la hija.

He intentado con algunos scripts que comprueban si la ventana tiene focus, que usan el SetIntervale etc pero no me funciona.

Ahora probe dejar un onBlur="self.focus()" en el body de la ventana hija y si funciona, al menos en el IE, pero para Firefox y Chrome no funciona.

Antes esto yo lo solucionaba usando la funcion ShowModalDialog, pero como tampoco funciona en estos 2 navegadores me tuve que pasar a Windows.open(), pero ya no se bloquea.

Alguien podria ayudarme en ese tema?, que estoy mutando una web de IE8 a los nuevos navegadores.

Saludos!

Comment: [ya no se puede](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog), va en contra de la experiencia del usuario. tendrás que manejarlo dentro de la misma ventana padre, o implementar [mensajes entre ventanas/pestañas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28230846/1423096)

Comment: No entiendo el voto negativo. La pregunta es concisa, ha detallado la investigación previa realizada y con las indicaciones que ha dado se puede comprender el problema sin la necesidad de código para reproducirlo.

Comment: Hola user3674768, como dice GGAle puedes usar JQuery (u otra librería) para crear la ventana modal. El hecho de que no se pueda usar showModalDialog no implica que no existan estas soluciones alternativas. En el fondo lo único que hay detrás es un elemento que ocupa toda la ventana que suele contener un elemento transparente o translúcido y la ventana que quieres mostrar.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás migrando a nuevos navegadores entonces tienes la posibilidad de usar jQuery y su Modal Form:
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Lo importante es ponerle un z-index a tu ventana modal y se quedará visible hasta que la cierres y no podrás usar la ventana padre.